# Mongo mapper use aggregation framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Can someone please point out my error, trying to sum a field(amount) using `userId` field?
https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/mongo-mapper

Here is my code, this is returning me all documents matched with userId but not the sum.

```
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$mapper = new \DB\Mongo\Mapper($f3->get('MongoDB'),'transactions');
        $filter = array('userId'=>'452');
        $options = array(
                  array(
                    'group' => array(
                        '_id' => array('userId' => $userId),
                        'amount' => array('$sum' => 'amount')
                    )
                  )
        );        
       $data =  $mapper->find($filter, $options);

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($data);
       exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo mapper uses the [db.collection.group()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) method rather than the aggregation framework. Therefore you won't be able to call accumulators such as `$sum`.

Instead you must use the following syntax:

```
$group = [
  'keys'=>['userId'=>1],
  'initial'=>['sum'=>0],
  'reduce'=>'function(obj,result){result.sum+=obj.amount;}',
  'finalize'=>'function(result){}',
);
$data =  $mapper->find($filter, ['group'=>$group]);
```

Comment: please let me know what it meant by `'userId'=>1`?

Comment: Is it a javascript code or Mongo code `function(obj,result){...}`?

Comment: `$group['keys']` should be an array that expresses the list of keys. The values of that array don't matter. It this example, it could as well be `['userId'=>TRUE]`, `['userId'=>NULL]` or `['userId'=>'whatever']`.

Comment: `function(obj,result){...}` is javascript.

Comment: Thanks, here are couple of things I did ;) 
1. function(obj,result){result.sum+=parseInt(obj.amount);}
2. If no recored then throw this error: `No write ops were included in the batch /lib/db/mongo/mapper.php:153`
    fixed with:` if(count($grp['retval']) > 0) $tmp->batchinsert($grp['retval'],['w'=>1]);`

Comment: can you please tell me how can I count total transactions against the userId and storeId? any suggestion would be helpful. thanks

Comment: In the same operation or in a new one?

Comment: Then you just need to set keys to `['userId'=>1,'storeId'=>1]` and increment a counter with `function(obj,result){result.count++;}`

Comment: Really helpful, perfect solution.

Comment: please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993255/php-f3-framework-use-aggregation-framework-pipeline-with-mongo-mapper

Comment: sorry for bothering you, I need your suggestion, I want to show record as group by `networkClass` but the issue is it only returning me the sum and networkClass name I need other fields as well, what should I do?   `$options['group'] = [
           'keys'=> ['networkClass' => 1],
     'initial' =>['sum'=>0],
     'reduce' => 'function(obj,result){}',
     'finalize'=>'function(result){}',
     ];`

Comment: You should include them in the reducing function. Without it, the engine can't guess what to do this those extra fields.