# php f3 framework use aggregation framework pipeline with mongo mapper

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I want to sue aggregation framework pipeline with  mongo mapper in the transaction table, the result should be something like this:
Suppose I have 7000 transactions in a collection with `status 1,2,3,4 (1=pending, 2=confirmed, 3=decline, 4=claimed)`

Data Representation:

```
Pending Count | Confirmed Count | Decline Count | Claimed Count
 4000                 2000            1000          0
```

1.
The issue is I'm not sure which field should be used for the key in the group.

2. My code is returning me all records which match the criteria.

please have a look at my code:

```
$filters = array('dateCreated'=>array(
                            '$gte'=>'2015-01-01', 
                            '$lte'=>'2017-05-15'
                    ));

 $group = [
              'keys' =>['userId'=>1],
              'initial' => ['pendingCount'=>0, 'confirmedCount'=>0, 'declineCount'=>0, 'claimedCount'=>0],
              'reduce'=>'
                      function(obj, result){

                        switch(result.status){
                            case 1:
                                result.pendingCount++;
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                result.confirmedCount++;
                                break;                          

                            case 3:
                                result.declineCount++;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                result.claimedCount++;
                                break;

                        }
                      }
                        ',
              'finalize'=>'function(result){}'
        ];

 $data =  $this->mapper->find($filter, ['group'=>$group]);
 echo "data<pre>";
 print_r($data);
```

Output:

Here you see it returning me more than one docments but I just want one record for all transaction, may be key `userId` should be replaced something 'null`

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [_id] => MongoId Object
>                   (
>                       [$id] => 591a8f5bb06b243d0262d0a1
>                   )
>
> ```
>         [userId] => 
>         [pendingCount] => 0
>         [confirmedCount] => 0
>         [declineCount] => 0
>         [claimedCount] =>0
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [_id] => MongoId Object
>             (
>                 [$id] => 591a8f5bb06b243d0262d0a2
>             )
>
>         [userId] => 
>         [pendingCount] => 0
>         [confirmedCount] => 0
>         [declineCount] => 0
>         [claimedCount] =>0
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [_id] => MongoId Object
>             (
>                 [$id] => 591a8f5bb06b243d0262d0a3
>             )
>
>         [userId] => 38730976
>         [pendingCount] => 0
>         [confirmedCount] => 0
>         [declineCount] => 0
>         [claimedCount] =>0
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [_id] => MongoId Object
>             (
>                 [$id] => 591a8f5bb06b243d0262d0a4
>             )
>
>         [userId] => 64920
>         [pendingCount] => 0
>         [confirmedCount] => 0
>         [declineCount] => 0
>         [claimedCount] =>0
>     )
> ```
>
> ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping by `userId` so you get one row per `userId`. Just pass an empty `keys` array to aggregate data against all records. Also there's a typo in your reducing function: it should be `obj.status`:

```
$group = [
  'keys' =>[],
  'initial' => ['pendingCount'=>0, 'confirmedCount'=>0, 'declineCount'=>0],
  'reduce'=>'
    function(obj, result){
      switch(obj.status){
        // etc.
      }
    }
  ',
  'finalize'=>'function(result){}'
];
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced key with `[]` and fixed typo `obj.status` now getting only one record with this output: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 591aa40ab06b244160a4101d
                )

            [endingCount] => 0
         [confirmedCount] => 0
         [declineCount] => 0
         [claimedCount] =>0
        )

)` I think issue is with switch statement

Comment: I'm sure there are records with different status.

Comment: now, it is working, I have just added double quotes inside `case "1": ...` but I'm not sure why MongoId Object is there?

Comment: The result of the grouping operation is a new *collection*. Therefore each *document* of that *collection* is assigned a unique `_id`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `$project` as described https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/ here? I want to use `$project`  at `dateCreated` field and want to display records count years wise like 2017==> 30(pending), 40(confirmed) and 2016=> 30(pending), 40(confirmed) and so on.

Comment: I don't think so because that syntax relates to the aggregation framework while the F3 Mongo mapper uses the `db.collection.group()` method. BTW, the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) states that "Mongodb 3.4 deprecates the db.collection.group() method", so it's maybe time to [request](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues) the framework to evolve on this.